# Trazer item de uma API em Swift

Tags: json, swift

Estou consumindo uma API Json e preciso trazer apenas um dos objetos que ela me retorna, mas não estou conseguindo, estou tentando o seguinte código:

```
let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
if httpStatus?.statusCode == 200 {
if data?.count != 0 {
    let respJson = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
    if let codigo = respJson ["codigo" as! Int]{
        print("Codigo: \(codigo)")
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {}
    }
}
```

Comment: `["codigo" as! Int]` Tá completamente errado. Não tem como force cast uma string para Int funcionar. Vai crash o seu app sempre. O correto é `if let codigo = respJson["codigo"] as? Int {`. Outra coisa é que você deve cast o seu resultado json para um dicionário e não um NSArray. `if let data = data, let respJson = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] {`. E verifique se o seu json contém mesmo um dicionário como top level object, se for um array de dicionários o cast do json seria para `[[String: Any]]` e você teria que mudar a maneira de pegar o seu código também.

Answer (score 0):

Não é porque esta faltando uma chave no código?

```
let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse
if httpStatus?.statusCode == 200 {
    if data?.count != 0 {
        let respJson = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
        if let codigo = respJson ["codigo" as! Int]{
            print("Codigo: \(codigo)")
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não amigo, copiei o código e esqueci de algumas chaves mesmo, o problema não é esse.

Answer (score 0):

Resposta feita levando em consideração o código publicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275439/variable-loses-value-when-it-exits-the-method). O seu problema é que voce ta executando um metodo nao sincronizado então quando voce tenth imprimir o resultado depots de iniciar o seu get o resultado kinda naoto establishment disponivel. O que voce precise é mover o seu print pra denture da closure do seu metodo nao sincronizado e adicionar um completion handler ao seu metodo IndicadoresInicial e passar o resultado quando terminado de dentro da sua closure:

Obs.: Como voce não postou o seu JSON eu não tenho como saber se ele contem uma ou mais rescisões. Caso contenha mais de uma voce tera de fazer a soma dentro do loop contido dos dicionários e chamar o completion handler depois de concluído o loop.

```
func indicadores(completion: @escaping (_ qdeRescisao: Int?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization":"\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "correctToken")!)"
    ]
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://10.1.80.106:9000/api/indicadores")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        do {
            if let dictionaries = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [[String: Any]] {
                for dictionary in dictionaries {
                    if let codigo = dictionary["codigo"] as? String, codigo == "rescisao", let qdeRescisao = dictionary["quantidade"] as? Int {
                        completion(qdeRescisao, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

---

Como fazer a chamada do metodo não sincronizado com o completion handler:

```
indicadores { qdeRescisao, error in
    guard let qdeRescisao = qdeRescisao else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")
        return
    }
    self.qtdTotalRescisao += qdeRescisao
    print("qtdTotalRescisao:", self.qtdTotalRescisao)
}
```